# Unable to send empty string values using DIO formdata

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

[image]

Like in this screenshot, formData is not allowing empty strings. N.B. they are not NULL for sure.

Sending data like this -

```
final payload = {
    'plate_number': formSubmissionData.data.plate_number, // this is a string
    'dynamic_form': formSubmissionData.data.dynamic_form, // this is an array of key value pairs [{'uuid': '', 'value': ''}]
};
FormData.fromMap(payload);
```

Does anyone have any solutions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Personally, I have no idea what I'm seeing there. What does "not allow" mean? Did you get a compile error? Runtime exception? Did the cops show up? I don't see any empty string either in what you show there. Is the field meant to be empty in your backend? Do you use an auto-generated client that already checks that for you? What does your code look like?

Comment: Basically that dynamic_form is in loop. And that form can have string/number/file. So If I send file/string, it takes as expected. But whenever I send empty string(""), it's not including in the payload. My Dynamic from payload like this - {"uuid": "someUuid", "value": "value"}. Using FormData by the way.

Comment: Basically Dio FormData ignoring the empty string. And that's why the red box mark has no value.